# Where can I get a contract review in Solidity? How much would it cost?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ether, contract-design, contract-deployment

Basically, I want to deploy a lottery contract, which by default should be very precise and secure, as all balance will be stored on the contract, and I have to track winner balances there as well. I have read some security issues and race conditions problems, but yet would be good to have some review from outside of my head.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Most recommendation questions are poorly specified magnets for spam and bikeshedding, so we don't accept questions of this type on any Stack Exchange site. 
 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/where-can-i-ask-about-finding-a-tool-library-or-favorite-off-site-resource

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Open Zeppelin](https://openzeppelin.org/) and [Consensys](https://new.consensys.net/) offer security reviews for smart contracts.

As far as a lottery is concerned the most basic issue that you might have is "finding" randomness to select the winner of the lottery.

To find randomness there are the following solutions:

1. Using the hash of the previous block. This method is susceptible to block withholding attacks. This means that the miner of the tx will know the winner when he runs the smart contract. Then he may choose not to add the mined block if the lottery outcome is not in his favor [[Source]](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4943/what-is-a-block-withholding-attack).
2. Using a randomness smart contract such as [RandDao](https://github.com/randao/randao). Haven't really used it, so I am unsure what security guarantees it offers.
3. Using an oracle service such as [oraclize](http://www.oraclize.it/). This solution could be secure in theory but you introduce a trusted party in your design.
4. Collect randomness from the users. This should be a generalized version of [Blum's coin flipping over the telephone](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1008911). The problem is this approach is that the protocol has two phase. The commit phase when parties commit to a random number and a reveal phase when parties reveal their randomness. To design such scheme you have to take into consideration that parties may choose to abort the protocol and not reveal their commits. Also this scheme is based on the ability of the user to provide randomness with high enough entropy (How random a string 123456 is ?).

In general, on chain randomness is an open problem. You can see the ethereum github page for other solutions that are not mentioned in my answer [Ethereum research](https://github.com/ethereum/research/wiki/Problems#21-on-chain-random-number-generation-63).

P.S. I am not affiliated with any of the companies mentioned above.
P.S. Hope my answer helps.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you have the money, you can see with [Zeppelin](https://openzeppelin.org/). You can check on this [Ethereum freelance platform](https://ethlance.com/) too. You could explore some subreddits or discord communities centered around Ethereum/smart-contracts and see if there are people willing to do it.

Answer (score 0):

@BokkyPooBah is a smart contract auditor. 
He has audited tons of smart-contracts. 
https://github.com/bokkypoobah

Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated.